# Rubber with separate instance for Sidekiq in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, rubber

I want to have a separate instance for running Sidekiq in my production environment.

Currently I have `db`, `web` and `app` instances and the `app` instance is taking care of sidekiq which is proving to be a wrong move.

I created a new instance with roles `redis`, `redis_master` and `sidekiq` but then when I SSH into it there is nothing running and if I do a `cap deploy` to it, during `bundle install` it says "dotenv" is only for instances with role `app` and it rolled back.

How do I set things up? Do I need to add app role to the Sidekiq instance for it to work?

**EDIT:**
Okay I've made it work by adding the `app` role to instance running `sidekiq`. Also I removed the `passenger` and `apache` roles from it manually so it does not start an app server. The only problem Im facing now is the fact that `rubber` is not automatically starting and stopping and restarting `sidekiq` during deploys. Need to figure that out.

Looking good though.

Comment: Hello Steve, could you figure out eventually what was the best approach to using SideKiq with Rubber?

Answer (score 0):

Are these ansible roles?

I'd recommend setting up a rails and ruby role (separately) in your ansible playbook, run the playbook in your new sidekiq-prod instance, then do a `cap prod deploy`

If you are using a rails app with capistrano to do your sidekiq deploys, you can access the rails env in your setup of `lib/capistrano/tasks/sidekiq.cap`:

`export RAILS_ENV=<%= fetch(:rails_env) %>`

Comment: Hi Sorry. These are 'rubber' roles.